# Seagate 8TB Barracuda drives to use in a usb3.0 docking station

Tags: docking-station

Just bought 2 Seagate 8TB drives to use in a usb3.0 docking station with my older Acer i3 laptop running Windows 7 64 bit. I plugged one of the new drives into the docking station and it was recognized, and ready to use but the new drive is not shown in My Computer listing. Do I have to install the drive(s) in a pc to format it before trying it in the HD dock?

Comment: You can assign a file system by using disk management

Comment: Submit an answer that details what you did

Answer (score 0):

No, the dock is a good way to do it.  Do some research into the Disk Management utility (called 'Create and format hard disk partitions' in Windows 10) and you'll get a good start.  Don't forget to let the HD spin down before physically moving it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. The disk mgmt utility worked - simple and fast. Thanks again.